# How to include external javascript library in PreactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia, preact

I'm currently one small project based on preactJS with algolia? I found that there is algolia component for reactjs but unfortunately, no algolia component for preactjs. That's why my problem is how can I include algolia javascript file into preactjs?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, I don't know if you see it but we have another flavor of InstantSearch, React-InstantSearch, that might integrate better with your preact app. Don't hesitate to give us your feedback about it.

Comment: @Marie I've tried with `React-InstantSearch` but when I rendered, I've encountered `process` error. That's why I've gave it up.

Comment: Could you open an issue on our github repository with the error you encountered? We need to investigate about that :)

Comment: @Marie sure, I've created ticket. https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/issues/264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert script dynamically, try this one:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.js";
    script.async = true;

    script.onload = function() {
       // init your algolia code here
    }

    document.body.appendChild(script);
},
```

Comment: `var client = algoliasearch('app', 'key');`
`var index = client.initIndex('my_index');`

`algoliasearch` gone undefined

Comment: ```algoliasearch``` will be defined only after script was loaded. Add this code to ```script.onload = () => {// your code //}``` block.

Comment: When I do this I get 'ReferenceError: document is not defined'. Any guesses about why?

Comment: @StormyKnight seems like you execute function before the document load. Make sure that your react build is insert inside <body> tag, not in the <head>

Answer (score 4):

Preact has component Head. To install it run

```
yarn add preact-head
```

Then it will be possible to specify standard head element such as script, meta, etc.. E.x. app.js

```
import Head from "preact-head";

export default class App extends Component {

        render() {
            return (
                <div id="app">
                    <Head>
                        <meta name="Whatever" />
                        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.js"></script>
                    </Head>

                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's so sweet and it was supposed to be correct answer if posted early.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the package [algoliasearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/algoliasearch) (if package is not correct, just search the desired package at https://npmjs.com)

Now you can do `npm install algoliasearch --save` at your root level where package.json is there and use it in your module like following -

`import algolia from 'algolia';`

And then use its methods in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it in your index.html between the head tags.
In React, the index.html is in `public/index.html`
In Preact, index.html is in `src/index.html`

```
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/instantsearch.js/1/instantsearch.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: In preact-cli, there is no html file. Only, .js file.

Comment: What about downloading the script to your assets and use `require('../assets/instantsearch.min.js');` (in index.js) ? Maybe also try the cdn url instead of the relative path but I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: Additionally, here's a preact example with index.html https://github.com/developit/preact-todomvc/blob/master/src/index.html